# entitiy framework .Skip not working correctly

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, jqgrid

i'm trying to make the navigation arrows in jqGrid working.
MVC 3 RC2, Entity Framework 4, .NET Framework 4, jqGrid 3.8.2

The Problem is, that i'm getting not record from 1 to 10, 11 to 20 and so on. It seems that the .skip method is not working correctly.

jqGrid calls the ActionResult with the right parameters.

Maybe you have an idea?

Regards,
float

```
    //
    // Post: /Admin/IndexGridData
    // Gibt ein JSON Result mit allen Aufträgen für das jqGrid zurück
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult IndexGridData(string sidx, string sord, int page, int rows)
    {

        // Ermittlung der Zusatzinformationen die das Grid anzeigt (Anzahl Aufträge, momentan angezeigte Aufträge
        int start = (page -1) * rows;
        int summeauftraege = _db.Auftrag.Where(x => x.AuftragStatus != "storno").Count();
        int totalPages = (int)Math.Ceiling((float)summeauftraege / (float)rows);

        var auftraege = (from auftrag in _db.Auftrag
                     .Include("KT_AuftragStatus")
                     .Include("KT_Bearbeitungsort")
                     .Include("AuftragPartner")
                         select new
                         {
                             Titel = auftrag.Titel,
                             Auftrag_GUID = auftrag.Auftrag_GUID,
                             Bearbeitungsort = auftrag.KT_Bearbeitungsort.Text,
                             AuftragStatus = auftrag.KT_AuftragStatus.Text,
                         }).Where(x => x.AuftragStatus != "storniert").OrderBy(x => x.Titel)
                     .Skip(start)
                     .Take(rows)
                     .AsEnumerable().ToList();

        // Sortierung des Grids anwenden
        if (sidx == "Titel" && sord == "asc")
        {
            auftraege = auftraege.OrderBy(x => x.Titel).AsEnumerable().ToList();
        }
        else if (sidx == "Titel" && sord == "desc")
        {
            auftraege = auftraege.OrderByDescending(x => x.Titel).AsEnumerable().ToList();
        }else if (sidx == "Bearbeitungsort" && sord == "asc")
        {
            auftraege = auftraege.OrderBy(x => x.Bearbeitungsort).AsEnumerable().ToList();
        }
        else if (sidx == "Bearbeitungsort" && sord == "desc")
        {
            auftraege = auftraege.OrderByDescending(x => x.Bearbeitungsort).AsEnumerable().ToList();
        }
        else if (sidx == "AuftragStatus" && sord == "asc")
        {
            auftraege = auftraege.OrderBy(x => x.AuftragStatus).AsEnumerable().ToList();
        }
        else if (sidx == "AuftragStatus" && sord == "desc")
        {
            auftraege = auftraege.OrderByDescending(x => x.AuftragStatus).AsEnumerable().ToList();
        }           


        // Erstellung des JSON Objekts welches die einzelnen Aufträge enthält
        var jsonauftraege = new object[auftraege.Count()];
        for (int i = 0; i < auftraege.Count; i++)
        {
            jsonauftraege[i] = new
            {
                id = auftraege[i].KA_Auftrag_GUID,
                cell = new[] { 
                "Details",
                "Bearbeiten",
                (auftraege[i].Titel != null) ? auftraege[i].Titel.ToString(): "&nbsp;", 
               (auftraege[i].Bearbeitungsort != null) ? auftraege[i].Bearbeitungsort.ToString(): "&nbsp;", 
                (auftraege[i].AuftragStatus != null) ? auftraege[i].AuftragStatus.ToString(): "&nbsp;", 
            }
            };
        }

        // Erstellung des JSON Results welches das Grid versteht
        var result = new JsonResult();
        result.Data = new { page = page, records = summeauftraege, rows = jsonauftraege, total = totalPages };

        return Json(result.Data);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is the solution:

```
    //
    // Post: /Admin/IndexGridData
    // Gibt ein JSON Result mit allen Aufträgen für das jqGrid zurück
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult IndexGridData(string sidx, string sord, int page, int rows)
    {

        // Ermittlung der Zusatzinformationen die das Grid anzeigt (Anzahl Aufträge, momentan angezeigte Aufträge
        int start = (page - 1) * rows;


       var auftraege = _db.Auftrag
                         .Where(x => x.AuftragStatus != "storno")
                         .OrderBy(x => x.Titel)
                         .Select(auftrag => new AuftragModels.GridAnsicht
                         {
                             Auftrag_GUID = auftrag.Auftrag_GUID,
                              Titel = auftrag.Titel,
                             Bearbeitungsort = auftrag.KT_Bearbeitungsort.Text,
                             AuftragStatus = auftrag.KT_AuftragStatus.Text,
                         }
                          );
        }


        // zusammen gesetztes SQL Statement speichern
        var sqlstring = ((ObjectQuery)auftraege).ToTraceString();

        // Sortierung des Grids anwenden
        if (sidx == "Titel" && sord == "asc")
        {
            auftraege = auftraege.OrderBy(x => x.Titel);
        }
        else if (sidx == "Titel" && sord == "desc")
        {
            auftraege = auftraege.OrderByDescending(x => x.Titel);
        }
        else if (sidx == "Bearbeitungsort" && sord == "asc")
        {
            auftraege = auftraege.OrderBy(x => x.Bearbeitungsort);
        }
        else if (sidx == "Bearbeitungsort" && sord == "desc")
        {
            auftraege = auftraege.OrderByDescending(x => x.Bearbeitungsort);
        }
        else if (sidx == "AuftragStatus" && sord == "asc")
        {
            auftraege = auftraege.OrderBy(x => x.AuftragStatus);
        }
        else if (sidx == "AuftragStatus" && sord == "desc")
        {
            auftraege = auftraege.OrderByDescending(x => x.AuftragStatus);
        }

        // zusammen gesetztes SQL Statement speichern
        //sqlstring = ((ObjectQuery)auftraege).ToTraceString();

        // aufträge zu einer Liste speichern, damit diese durchlaufen werden kann
        var auftragListe = auftraege
                         .AsEnumerable().ToList();

        // Anzahl der Seiten berechnen
        int summeauftraege = auftragListe.Count();
        int totalPages = (int)Math.Ceiling((float)summeauftraege / (float)rows);

        // nur die Aufträge anzeigen, die auf eienr Seite sichtbar sind
        auftragListe = auftragListe
                         .Skip(start)
                         .Take(rows)
                         .AsEnumerable().ToList();

        // Erstellung des JSON Objekts welches die einzelnen Aufträge enthält
        var jsonauftraege = new object[auftragListe.Count()];
        for (int i = 0; i < auftragListe.Count(); i++)
        {
            jsonauftraege[i] = new
            {
                id = auftragListe[i].Auftrag_GUID,
                cell = new[] { 
                "Details",
                "Bearbeiten",
                (auftragListe[i].Titel != null) ? auftragListe[i].Titel.ToString(): "&nbsp;", 
                (auftragListe[i].Bearbeitungsort != null) ? auftragListe[i].Bearbeitungsort.ToString(): "&nbsp;", 
                (auftragListe[i].AuftragStatus != null) ? auftragListe[i].AuftragStatus.ToString(): "&nbsp;", 
            }
            };
        }

        // Erstellung des JSON Results welches das Grid versteht
        var result = new JsonResult();
        result.Data = new { page = page, records = summeauftraege, rows = jsonauftraege, total = totalPages };

        return Json(result.Data);
    }
```

Comment: Maybe somebody has a solution for these if statements for sorting the Grid?

Answer (score 1):

`.OrderBy()` on the outer query is required to come *before* `.Skip()`. As far as I can see, doing it the way you have it should not even work. If it works at all you're probably in object space, not L2E. You must order *before* you skip or take.

Comment: Can you tell me where to do the .OrderBy()? I've moved it after the .Include() methods, but it's the same as before.

Comment: After `Include` and `Where` before `Skip`. I suspect you have `Where` calls after your `OrderBy`, which will cause the `OrderBy` to be discarded.

Comment: On second glance, it's sort of odd to be mixing language integrated LINQ with "dotted" syntax. I think it should still be OK, but try calling `Select()` instead of `select`

Comment: How can i trace the SQL in Visual Studio? Btw. i'm not using MS SQL Server.

Comment: The reason why i'm using select is that i don't know how to select this values via Select()

Comment: To trace SQL, use `var sql = (query as ObjectQuery).ToTraceString();` To select values with `Select()` you do `_db.Auftrag.Include(...).Select(a => new { ... }).Skip(...`

Comment: Now the Select Statement uses only Method-based query syntax. Here is the Trace: http://codepaste.net/e94hbz and here my changed action: http://codepaste.net/f7gjv7

Comment: Is it possible, that the sybase dataprovider has problems with the translation from entity framework to the database?

Comment: Because you are projecting, you probably don't need the Includes. True, it shouldn't change the Take and yes, it might be a provider bug, but you can work around it in this case.

Comment: What do you mean with projecting? Dont i need the includes to show long text values and not the short values. How to work arround this?

Comment: Projection: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/93645/LINQ-to-Entities-Projection.aspx Not sure what you mean by "long text". I don't think you need `Include()` here.

Comment: I need the Include(), because i want to resolve text of key values. The user who is getting the result of the sql statement doesn't know what "eroffen" means. I mean, Bearbeitungsort in table Auftrag can be "eroffen" (key) where the text translation (from KT_Bearbeitungsort) would be "erneut offen".

Comment: So just include those fields in your projection, in addition to the other fields already in your `Select()`

Comment: I thought that i can't include them without joining the tables where these fields are in. Visual Studio only suggest the fields i need, when i join the tables whith Include(). Or i'm missing something?

Comment: No, that is not true. `Include()` is not required for anything *inside* a L2E query.

Comment: Great! I didn't know that. But i where wrong, the query selects still the same records :(

Comment: The solution was to select all records in a variable a and then skip and take records from a and save them to variable b...

Comment: I talked to the Sybase support. They found out that it's a bug in their .NET Dataprovider. So, my solution was a trick to avoid their bug.